# How to achieve this layout in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'd like to re-create this layout but I really can't find a working combination of widget:

[image]

I have a `Scaffold` (black) and inside the body I have to put the red and blue widgets. Can't use `bottomSheet` because I need to pass variables between red and blue, so everything has to be done inside Scaffold body.

Comment: could you include what you have done so far?

Comment: It would be difficoult because I have BlocBuilders inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this snippet

```dart
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AppBar"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  tileColor: index.isEven ? Colors.green : Colors.amber,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("fixed"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: ""),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.abc), label: "")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

With forloop body, make sure to handle scrollable

```dart
body: Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: Column(
      children: [
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
          ListTile(
            tileColor: index.isEven ? Colors.green : Colors.amber,
          )
      ],
    )),
    Container(
      height: 100,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text("fixed"),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: is it possible not to use ListView? I'm working with blocBuilder and the items are rendered with for-loop as Column children

Comment: Yes, you can have for loop with column, But for list Better to use .builder

Comment: Tested, perfectly working

Answer (score 0):

You can use following package. It will help to resolve your issue.

```
persistent_bottom_nav_bar:
```

You can find [here](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)